# How to divide the input taken from user in two parts and assign them to two different arrays in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, structure

If we take the input from user by asking them, like below:

```
cout << "Enter your course code and course name: ";
```

Now if the user enters `CS201 Introduction to Programming`, how can I only assign the code part, i.e. `CS201` to an array, let's say;

```
char courseCode[10];
```

And how can I assign the name part in the array, let's say:

```
char courseName[50];
```

I want to do this to 5 students, using the structure defined below:

```
struct student
{
    char courseName[50];
    char courseCode[10];
};

student stu[5];
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/split-a-string-in-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem using the `cin.getline()` functions to get the string in token pointer and then used `strchr(char [], cahr)` of `<string>` header file to separate the current string from the place where the first white space comes. Then I copied both separated strings into my desired elements of my structure using `strcpy()` function.

Answer (score 3):

It's actually kind of simple once you remember that the input operator `>>` stops on white-space, and also know about the [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) function.

Then you can do something like

```
std::string courseCode;
std::string courseName;

std::cin >> courseCode;
std::getline(std::cin, courseName);
```

Note that I use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) for the strings instead of arrays. This is what you *really* should use. If you're not allowed (by your teacher or something) and *must* use arrays, then you can't use `std::getline` but instead have to use [`std::istream::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline) instead.

Comment: "_If you're not allowed (by your teacher or something) then send him to the cpp lounge and we'll deal with it_" FIFY.

Comment: @Some programmer dude I can use strings and allowed to, but to make myself more strong in arrays, I want to use arrays here. Secondly, the code you wrote:

`std::getline(std::cin, courseName);`

How would it assign the course name (taken from user with teh course code as input) to courseName string?

Comment: @KhubaibKhawar The `std::getline` function will read the rest of the line and store it in the string provided as the second argument.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thats fine now. Well, I am not understanding that how would it split the code and assign it to courseCode string? because there is not anything finding any whitespace in the code you explained.

Comment: @KhubaibKhawar Like I said in my answer, the input operator `>>` will handle it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Store the input in a single string say `x`

Now on `x` perform linear search for the first whitespace and split the string about the first whitespace. Store the two resultant strings in your struct.

Comment: Lets say, I used the linear search and stored the first input in courseCode array, after finding the white space, now how do I assign the left string which is the course name in the courseName array?